# Web scraping javascript based websites using selenium gives error

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I've been working on a project to send a few numbers to a specific discord server scraped from a javascript based website. I've gotten to the point where I only need to scrape the numbers, but I am having issues with it. When I try to get the numbers, this error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cukor4_dry.py", line 48, in <module>
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "mainbgsection")))
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

code I use:

```
#import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from twill.commands import *
import pyautogui
import os
import subprocess
from dhooks import Webhook, File
import sys

#set settings
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)

hook = Webhook('webhook link')

    time.sleep(4)
    print('form')
    showforms()

    try:
        #try to log into page
        webdriver.get('url')
        webdriver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('username')
        webdriver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('password')
        webdriver.find_element_by_name('actionButton').click()
        print('submit')
    except:
        #already logged in
        pass
    print('waited')

    #try to scrape the website
    url = "url"
    webdriver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "mainbgsection")))
```

Comment: it says to you that `#mainbgsection` is not visible ... may be you should wait more time OR change Expected Conditions logic ... it is hard to answer without actual url which you trying to parse

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions